# Android is one thread can handle multiple socket?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets, kotlin

In my Android Project, I have to create multiple client socket on peers, and keep the connection active until i have received a specific message. (one socket per peer and we talk about 100 socket so creating 100 threads is too much)

For the moment, I create one thread per socket but I think it's too much for the device because I have this message running quickly:

```
2020-04-23 13:51:31.539 29982-30306/application: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
2020-04-23 13:51:31.541 29982-30216/application: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
2020-04-23 13:51:31.550 29982-30306/application: WaitForGcToComplete blocked Alloc on ProfileSaver for 11.793ms
2020-04-23 13:51:31.550 29982-30306/application: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
2020-04-23 13:51:31.551 29982-30216/application: WaitForGcToComplete blocked Alloc on ProfileSaver for 9.578ms
```

Is there a way that a thread can handle multiple socket to avoid too many thread on the device ?

Maybe Kotlin coroutines can help here ?

Comment: why don't you use non-blocking library to accomplish this?

Comment: I would like to use as less as possible third library in order to understand socket programmation and reduce dependencies, but winch library would u suggest?

Comment: if you use kotlin you can use https://ktor.io/servers/raw-sockets.html ktor's non blocking server sockets, instead of using runBlocking as mentioned in there you can use coroutineScope{} as well.

Comment: Ok I upvote and will try ur solution this afternoon but waiting for native solution too. thx buddy

Comment: @Sercuio there is java.nio package packed with SocketChannel out of the box with jdk, but it will be compllicated to use.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu So i changed all my code for using ktor and coroutines but I have always the message saying the garbage collector is blocked. Maybe I badly manage my sockets...